# ElasticsearchAutoConfiguration not available in spring boot autoconfigure 2.7.6

Tags: spring-boot

I am working on spring-boot upgrade from 2.2.2.Release to 2.7.6. I am noticing org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchAutoConfiguration is not available in spring-boot-autoconfigure:2.7.6. Is there any substitute for ElasticsearchAutoConfiguration class which is introduced in 2.7.6 version.

I checked the spring boot project source code but didn't find the ElasticsearchAutoConfiguration class present in latest version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchAutoConfiguration` class was removed in favor of `ElasticsearchDataAutoConfiguration` in the same package in [b780e52](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/b780e5247c049902c5cda8b2c94dc74a69bb3984) since Spring Boot 2.3.0.

See also https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/19668.